# Get Facebook username using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

I am using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithfql as a reference but in that guide it says to have this line of code

```
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
```

However in the SDK I do not see a file called facebook.php. Am I missing something?

I am trying to use PHP to get the current logged in user's username.

Comment: That is for the old SDK v3, the new v4 has a totally different structure. And FQL is deprecated. That whole thing is outdated, try and find something more up to date, f.e. under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

Comment: Furthermore, you cannot get the `username` anymore with Graph API>= v2.0